# Python remove stop words from pandas dataframe give wrong output

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, glob

I remove the stopword from multiple files. First I read each file and remove the stop word from the dataframe. After that I concatenate the dataframe with the next dataframe. When I print the dataframe it gives me an output like:

```
0      [I,  ,  ,  ,  , r, e,  , h,  , h,  , h, v, e, ...      
1      [D,  , u,  , e, v, e, n,  , e,  , h, e,  , u, ...     
2      [R, g, h,  , f, r,  , h, e,  , e, c, r,  , w, ...     
3      [A, f, e, r,  , c, l, l, n, g,  , n,  , p, l, ...     
4      [T, h, e, r, e,  , v, e, r, e, e, n,  ,  , n, ...
```

Here is my code:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(ROOT_DIR + '/' + DATASET + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
stop = stopwords.words('english') 
for file_ in allFiles:
    chunkDataframe = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0, chunksize=1000)
    dataframe = pd.concat(chunkDataframe, ignore_index=True)
    dataframe['Text'] = dataframe['Text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
    print dataframe
    list_.append(dataframe)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

Please help me optimize the way to read multiple files with removed stop word from it.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataframe['Text']` contains a single string, not a list of words. So if you iterate over it using `lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop]` you iterate over it character by character and generate a list of characters as a result. To iterate over it word by word, change it to:

```
lambda x: [item for item in string.split(x) if item not in stop]
```

Comment: in a situation like this, how to I get the result to properly appear? When I try to use this I get: <function __main__.<lambda>>